# Not sending full file size always -1

Tags: python, file, p2p, sharing

This code is supposed to be a p2p file sharing python code. It sends the file, but it doesn't send the full size. I don't know what is wrong that it is doing that. First I encountered decoding errors and searched it and got the encoder. Other than that the file was not showing and it was fixed. Now the file is showing but it isn't sending the full size. When I try opening the sent file I get "corrupted" or "wrong file type"
this is server.py

```
import os
import socket
import time
import math

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), 12000))
sock.listen(10)
print("Host Name: ", sock.getsockname())

client, addr = sock.accept()
print("Connected to : ", addr)

file_name = input("File Name:")
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
print("File Size: ", file_size)
client.send(file_name.encode("ISO-8859-1"))
client.send(str(file_size).encode("ISO-8859-1"))

with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
    c = 0

    start_time = time.time()

    while c <= file_size:
        ChunkAnnouncer = math.ceil(math.ceil(c) / 5)
        print("Chunk Size: ", ChunkAnnouncer)

        data = file.read(4096)
        if not (data):
            break
        client.sendall(data)
        c += len(data)

    end_time = time.time()

print("File Transfer Complete.Total time: ", end_time - start_time)
sock.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket
import time
import os

host = input("Host Name: ")
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    sock.connect((host, 12000))
    print("Connection Successful")
    print("Connected to: ",(host, 12000))
except:
    print("Connection Failed")
    exit(0)

file_name = sock.recv(100).decode()
file_size = sock.recv(100).decode()
print(file_name)
start_time = time.time()
sock.send(file_name.encode())
confirmation = sock.recv(1024)
encoding="ISO-8859-1"
if confirmation.decode(encoding) == "file-doesn't-exist":
    print("File Doesn't Exist")
else:
 write_name = 'from_server '+file_name
 if os.path.exists(write_name) : os.remove(write_name)
with open(write_name, 'wb') as file :
        while 1:
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            file.write(data)
            end_time = time.time()
print(file_name, ' Downloaded Successfully')
print("Elapsed Time: " ,end_time - start_time)
```

I honestly can't see the error. if you can help..

Comment: What is `confirmation`?

Comment: @po.pe just a random variable to store sock.recv(1024) nothing important.

Comment: But is there something to receive? How big is the file you send and what do you receive?

Comment: @po.pe a simple .jpg file size 10KB nothing too big, I receive the file but it is always -1KB like if the .jpg file is 10KB I get 9KB if a 80KB I get 79KB, and I can't see the error

Comment: Remove the line `confirmation = sock.recv(1024)` and try again

Comment: Did solve your issue?

Comment: I removed the confirmation and nothing happened. still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the `client.py` as follows and it worked

```
import socket
import time
import os

host = input("Host Name: ")
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    sock.connect((host, 12000))
    print("Connection Successful")
    print("Connected to: ",(host, 12000))
except:
    print("Connection Failed")
    exit(0)

file_name = sock.recv(100).decode()
file_size = sock.recv(100).decode()
print(file_name)
start_time = time.time()
# sock.send(file_name.encode())
# confirmation = sock.recv(1024)
# encoding="ISO-8859-1"
# if confirmation.decode(encoding) == "file-doesn't-exist":
#     print("File Doesn't Exist")
# else:
write_name = 'from_server '+file_name
if os.path.exists(write_name):
    os.remove(write_name)
with open(write_name, 'wb') as file :
        while 1:
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            file.write(data)
            end_time = time.time()
print(file_name, ' Downloaded Successfully')
print("Elapsed Time: " ,end_time - start_time)
```

The thing is that your server doesn't treat the response from client

```
# sock.send(file_name.encode())
```

and also doesn't send the confirmation.